# Jquery Ajax and PHP generated dynamically different forms

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, submit

The problem lies with PHP, say I have Jquery and I ask 3 inputs field with a form. Once i submit that form I go through PHP and say I have :

```
$_POST['service1']
$_POST['service2']
$_POST['service3']
```

that's fine. I would hard code these values in the PHP **but say I ask for 5 services or 9** services ... I'm stuck trying to figure this out.

I thought about one way to do it would be with **fopen and fclose and write a file to disk** on the server side depending on how many fields I requested.

Basicly the app is suppose to grab how many service I need add to it the content for each of these and then generated an SQL query with all of these ... But since the form is dynamic I'm stuck trying to figure out how I would write the PHP side of it.

Comment: I don't understand the whole thing with files, but have you thought about using `<input name="service[]">`?  This will make `$_POST['service']` an array

Comment: I;m already using this method to get the POST data back ...`<?php
 $defaultFile = "postedvars.php";
 $openFile = fopen($defaultFile, 'w+');
 $content = "<?php\n";
 $writeToFile = fwrite($openFile, $content);
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
  echo $key. " ".$value;
  $content = "$".$key."=\"".$value."\";\n";
  $writeToFile = fwrite($openFile, $content);
  }
 $content = "\n"."?>";
 $writeToFile = fwrite($openFile, $content);
 fclose($openFile);
 echo "Successfully written to disk";
?>
`

Answer (score 0):

Use array of service fields something like

```
<input name="service[]" />
<input name="service[]" />
<input name="service[]" />
....
```

than on server side you will receive $_POST['service'] as array, than you can easily iterate through each element of service array and process it